# Limit FTP client ports?

Tags: iptables, ftp, port

Okay so I use the simple linux ftp client to download/upload files off ftp servers. I have an iptables firewall which blocks most of the ports and I have to close the firewall for it to work. Although port 21 is open but I guess that explains why the download works and not the upload. The following command works perfectly with the firewall on:

```
wget ftp://user:pass@server.com
```

I just have problems when I actually connect to the server and try to "put"/upload a file to the server. Here is an example netstat output of the port used at that time but it's always different.

```
netstat -a | grep ServerIP
tcp        0 197520 myIP.:59622 ServerIP:ftp-data ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 myIP.:40341 ServerIP:ftp      ESTABLISHED
```

Both the ports on myIP range are blocked and I'm failing to guess what ports do I have to open. Google search fails as well. Secondly, if I try something like this on iptables, it gives me an error:

```
-A INPUT -p tcp --match multiport --dport 40000:40500 -j ACCEPT
iptables-restore v1.4.8: too many ports specified
```

Secondly, why would I need to open the ports when I have the following line before the ports were blocked in the configuration file:

```
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible cause is that you use active FTP.

FTP has an active and a passive mode.

---

Active:

> In active mode FTP the client connects from a random unprivileged port
>   (N > 1023) to the FTP server's command port, port 21. Then, the client
>   starts listening to port N+1 and sends the FTP command PORT N+1 to the
>   FTP server. The server will then connect back to the client's
>   specified data port from its local data port, which is port 20.

Passive:

> In order to resolve the issue of the server initiating the connection
>   to the client a different method for FTP connections was developed.
>   This was known as passive mode, or PASV, after the command used by the
>   client to tell the server it is in passive mode. In passive mode FTP
>   the client initiates both connections to the server, solving the
>   problem of firewalls filtering the incoming data port connection to
>   the client from the server. When opening an FTP connection, the client
>   opens two random unprivileged ports locally (N > 1023 and N+1). The
>   first port contacts the server on port 21, but instead of then issuing
>   a PORT command and allowing the server to connect back to its data
>   port, the client will issue the PASV command. The result of this is
>   that the server then opens a random unprivileged port (P > 1023) and
>   sends P back to the client in response to the PASV command. The client
>   then initiates the connection from port N+1 to port P on the server to
>   transfer data.

-- [Active FTP vs. Passive FTP, a Definitive Explanation](http://slacksite.com/other/ftp.html#active)

---

This means that you have two options:

1. Easy option: Use the passive mode
2. Hard option: Allow incoming connections from port 20, from any host which you have already an established connection from.

I'd choose option 1

Comment: I know that already but I don't see PASV might help because it has to be dealing with ports that are blocked as well. So whether it's PASV or Active, it has to use some ports and I only have a small range of accepted ports and those too are rate-limited to some extent.

Comment: I see now. Well it's impossible to predict the ports of the outgoing traffic. The system chooses for every application a random port unless the application is a server and binds a specific socket. Therefore you should manage the rules on basis of the destination port.

Comment: Any ideas why does the rule of accepting ESTABLISHED state doesn't work?

Comment: @AsadMoeen The ESTABLISHED rule is not working because it matches established streams, not established IPs. In other words, it's going to match things based on the 5-tuple (source IP, dest IP, protocol, source port, dest port). See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

To accomplish option 2 from [Christopher Perrin's answer](https://serverfault.com/a/524515/53816), you can use the [`recent`](http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables-extensions.man.html#lbBU) match extension. It adds source IP address to a list that you can check against in subsequent rules. For these rules, I've assumed `eth0` is your WAN interface.

```
iptables -A FORWARD -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 21 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -m recent --name trustedftp --set
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -p tcp --sport 20 -m recent --name trustedftp --seconds 30 --rcheck -j ACCEPT
```

I haven't tested this, but I think it should work.